# Angular 2: window.crypto.subtle.importKey works in 'localhost' but not on 'ip'

Tags: javascript, angular, encryption, webcrypto-api

I am a rookie in Angular 2. I am trying to implement a login form that sends the emailid and password after certain encryption steps to the server.

I have implemented AES-ECB by using AES-CTR from,

https://github.com/diafygi/webcrypto-examples

I have used the '*importKey*' and '*encrypt*' method as follows,

```
public deriveAKey(input, encryptKey, cryptoIV) {

    var ref: TopDivComponent = this;
    console.log('Testing before importKey...');

    window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
        "raw",
        ref.stringToArrayBuffer(encryptKey),
        {
            name: "AES-CTR",
        },
        true,
        ["encrypt"]
    ).then(function (key) {
        console.log('Inside then...');
        var newvar = ref.stringToArrayBuffer(cryptoIV);
        var encrypt = window.crypto.subtle.encrypt(
            {
                name: "AES-CTR",
                counter: newvar,
                length: 128,
            },
            key,
            ref.stringToArrayBuffer(input)
        ).then(function (encrypted) {
            var temp = ref.arrayBufferToString(encrypted);
            console.log('Encrypted First: ' + encrypted);
            console.log('Temp: ' + temp);
            console.log('Key: ' + key);
            let fin_encrypted = btoa(temp);
            // console.log('Encrypted Snc/d: ' + fin_encrypted);
            ref.response(fin_encrypted);
            // console.log('From deriveKey: ' + fin_encrypted);
        });
    });
}
```

I use a local server to obtain the response. Everything works fine when using localhost. The Request and Response are properly sent and obtained from the server. But, when connected over IP, it shows an error **“NotSupportedError: Only secure origins are allowed”**.

When I used *Chrome canary*, it said that importKey method is not recognized. So when I 'console'ed it with Chrome, the control did not go beyond the importKey method. What could possibly be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome restricts the usage of WebCryptographyApi to secure origins. It means 'https'. `localhost` is a special address enabled for development. Therefore, to use WebCrypto in a real environment you need to setup a SSL/TLS server